# ajax load different php pages

Tags: php, jquery

How can I call functions on different pages?

For example if I click on the start button, it will run the code necessary to start the tomcat server.

Here is the code for the main page:

```
<input name="submit" class= "green" id ="start" type="submit" value=" Start ">
<input name="submit" id = "stop" class='red' type="submit" value=" Stop ">
```

Here's the second page that executes the program.

```
function (tomcatstart){
  $ssh->exec('service tomcat start');}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches you can take to accomplish this sort of task. Here's how I would do it:

Firstly, I'd replace the `<input>` tags with `<button>` tags. This is more personal preference than a real change in functionality, but since you're sending the request via AJAX, you don't need a form or inputs.

Secondly, I'd create the JS functions to make the AJAX request, something like this:

```
function start() {
    $.post('urlToStart.php', {
         data : 'Some data'
     }, function(returnedData) {
         //Optionally do something with the returned data, like alert 'Success' or 'Failed'
         alert(returnedData);
     });
}
```

Finally, you need a php page to handle the request. You can either have one page that handles both the `start` and `stop` requests, or you can have different pages for each one.

Example `urlToStart.php`:

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['data'];
if($data !== null) {
    tomcatstart();
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Failed: " . print_r(error_get_last()); //Get the error message so you know what happened
}

function tomcatstart(){
  $ssh->exec('service tomcat start');
}
```

And that should set you on your way

Comment: thank you..step 1 changed to button and  i added  onclick="start()" value="start" ..step 2 changed to <script>              
        function start() {
         $.post('main.php', {
         data : 'start'
     }, function(returnedData) {
         //Optionally do something with the returned data, like alert 'Success' or 'Failed'
         alert("Start Successfuly");
     });
}   and last if($data == start) but still not working

Comment: In your php file, make sure you have quotes around the word `start`, as it's a string

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

1. Add data-task attribute, so we can write single ajax to for
   all
2. Add an additional class, `trigger-ajax`
3. change inputs to button or change the input type to button
4. make a jquery call on click event, using class we added

   ```
   jQuery(".trigger-ajax").on('click', function(){
   var _context = jQuery(this);
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxrequest.php',
       type: "post",
       data:{
           task: _context.attr('data-task')
       },
       success:function(response){
           console.log(response)
       }
   })
   });
   ```
5. handle it in php

   ```
   if(!empty($_POST['task'])){

       switch(trim(strtotlower($_POST['task']))){
           case "start-tomcat":
                $ssh->exec('service tomcat start');
               break;
           case "stop-tomcat":
                $ssh->exec('service tomcat stop');
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you.done with another solution.anyway this is also good for me.will try soon